# Angled Extrude Path

Tags: three.js

It appears that when I try to extrude a Mesh that is aligned with say x-axis with an extrude path that is at 45 degree angle with the x-axis, then my original mesh is no longer rendered to as x-axis aligned. Instead it's rotated to maintain a perpendicular angle with extrude path.

How can I change the extrude angle without changing the front mesh orientation ?

The following did not work as it rotates the front mesh too :

```
new THREE.LineCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1));
```

Comment: See if applying a shear matrix to the mesh geometry works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537141/how-to-shear-a-cube-in-three-js/12537770#12537770

Comment: interesting solution, i'll give it a try. thanks. On another note, is it possible to extrude different corners of a mesh toward different directions? I have a wall with holes (windows) and I like to extrude window holes parallel to z-axis, but have the corners of the wall extrude a little inward so that there is no z-fighting with neighboring walls.

Comment: You would have to manipulate the vertices yourself after the extrusion and then recompute normals, etc.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25626171/1697459

Comment: I ended up abandoning the extrude method and basically implemented my own version by pushing the back mesh in the direction of neg normal vector of the front mesh.