# ThreeJS - ExtrudeGeometry depth gives different result than extrudePath

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I use THREE.ExtrudedGeometry in two different ways and I expected the same result.

Once I use the depth to set the extrusion options.
Another time I use an extrude path which is a line from `Vector3(0, 0, 0)` to `Vector3(0, 0, depth)`

The strange thing is that the resulting geometry is unsuspectingly rotated around the Z-axis. 
Why is this? Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

A **fiddle** can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/yfkd85s8/1/) and this is my code:

---

Common variables:

```
// Material for mesh
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000});

// Depth to extrude
var depth = 10;

// Shape to extrude
var shape = new THREE.Shape([
    new THREE.Vector2( -20,-60 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( -20, 60 ),
    new THREE.Vector2(  20, 60 ),
    new THREE.Vector2(  20,-60 )
]);
```

Here using depth:

```
var extrudeSettings1 = {
    bevelEnabled: false,
    steps: 1,
    amount: depth
};

var geometry1 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings1 );

var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material );

mesh1.position.set( -50, 0, 0 );

scene.add( mesh1 );
```

Now using a path

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

var v2 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, depth );

var path = new THREE.LineCurve3( v1, v2 )

var extrudeSettings2 = {
    bevelEnabled: false,
    steps: 1,
    extrudePath: path
};

var geometry2 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings2 );

var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material );

mesh2.position.set( 50, 0, 0 );

scene.add( mesh2 );
```

**EDIT1:**

Updated `position.set()` after WestLangley his comment

**EDIT2:**

I gave it another thought, but I don't understand WestLangley his answer. The orientation of the shape does not matter for being able to end up on the starting point. Either way the shape is able to have the same orientation as it started.

To illustrate I draw two shapes in the x, y plane and I show the extrusion of the in my opinion only correct result:

[image: shapes]
[image: expected extrusion geometry]

Comment: Tip: in three.js r.68, the pattern `mesh.position = new THREE.Vector3( 50, 0, 0 );` is no longer valid. Use `mesh.position.set( 50, 0, 0 );` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the behavior can be explained if you look into the source code of `THREE.ExtrudedGeometry` and `THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames`

here's in the comments of ExtrudeGeometry

> - extrudePath:  // 3d spline path to extrude shape along. (creates Frames if .frames aren't defined)
> - frames:  // containing arrays of tangents, normals, binormals

so essentially, like WestLangley says, if `extrudePath` is specific, the geometry is extruded along a 3d spline path, and uses FrenetFrames for adjustment of rotation, unlike the simple approach of a normal extrusion.

In `THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames` you might see commented code for the initialNormal1. You might uncomment those if you wish to explore different intial positions, or pass in a FrenetFrames of your intended behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the arbitrary orientation or set the initial orientation manually with ExtrudeGeometry (or ExtrudeBufferGeometry)?

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong. What you are seeing is a consequence of how the algorithm is implemented. Consider it a "feature".

When you extrude a shape along a path, the shape is free to "spin", and the initial orientation is arbitrary.

Imagine if you were extruding along a closed 3D loop. When you get back to the starting point, the shape must have the same orientation it started with, so the ends of the extrusion match up. The algorithm must have the flexibility to handle this situation.

EDIT: When you extrude along a path, the algorithm computes a series of slowly-varying [Frenet Frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas). (Look at the Wikipedia animations.) These Frenet Frames determine how the shape is oriented along the path. The extrusion algorithm determines the orientation of the initial Frenet Frame, and that initial orientatioin can result in a "spinning" of the shape.

three.js r.68

Comment: I don't totally understand your answer. I understand that a shape might need to spin during extrusion, but I edited my question to illustrate why I think it should not spin randomly.

Comment: Sorry, I can only tell you how the current algorithm is implemented -- even if you think it should be different. What if you were extruding along a line segment in 3D that pointed in an arbitrary direction? How should the shape be oriented in that case? The answer is it is arbitrary.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the arbitrary orientation or set the initial orientation manually with ExtrudeGeometry (or ExtrudeBufferGeometry)?