# Extrude geometry vertically only along a curve/polyline

Tags: three.js

I am trying to extrude rectangle along a curve path. Problem here is the shape is twisting for various curves. Is there a way where irrespective how curve bends, it will always extrude shape in same orientation i.e it should not twist shape.

The end result are different. Here I wish to draw uniform rectangle orientation. If it is a feature behaviour like this, how should I approach for a work around to make shape orientation uniform.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Extruded Buffer Issue along path</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Vishal D" />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        border: 1px blue solid;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import * as THREE from "./three.module.js";
      import { OrbitControls } from "./OrbitControls.js";
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        45,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        10000
      );
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

      var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
      var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(cube);

      const size = 2000;
      const divisions = 100;

      const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
      scene.add(gridHelper);

      // Add shape 1
      const rawPoints1 = [
        { x: -811.4902770929039, y: -1401.3931087367237, z: 80.33 },
        { x: -810.239964377135, y: -1402.0211585126817, z: 81.08 },
        { x: -804.0070621669292, y: -1404.9163141585886, z: 81.31 },
        { x: -796.6638076193631, y: -1408.3935632109642, z: 81.58 },
        { x: -790.4402361027896, y: -1411.441899254918, z: 81.81 },
        { x: -779.4486810080707, y: -1416.9871105961502, z: 82.21 },
        { x: -771.4336166419089, y: -1421.1996304765344, z: 82.51 },
        { x: -767.3094508089125, y: -1423.405458174646, z: 82.66 },
        { x: -757.7921450398862, y: -1428.5523871444166, z: 83.01 },
        { x: -755.1702206097543, y: -1429.9923011995852, z: 83.73 },
      ];
      const points1 = [];
      rawPoints1.forEach((point) => {
        points1.push(new THREE.Vector3(point.x + 800, point.z, point.y + 800));
      });
      const randomSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points1);
      const extrudeSettings = {
        steps: 30,
        bevelEnabled: false,
        extrudePath: randomSpline,
      };

      const wallShape = new THREE.Shape();
      const wallHeight = 10 / 2;
      const wallWidth = 5 / 2;
      wallShape.moveTo(0, 0);
      wallShape.lineTo(wallHeight, 0);
      wallShape.lineTo(wallHeight, wallWidth);
      wallShape.lineTo(0, wallWidth);

      const shape1Geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(
        wallShape,
        extrudeSettings
      );
      const material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
      const mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(shape1Geometry, material1);
      scene.add(mesh1);

      // Add shape 2
      const rawPoints2 = [
        { x: -768.261181384325, y: -1452.8930274173617, z: 75.51 },
        { x: -767.7200012542307, y: -1453.9499824345112, z: 75.97 },
        { x: -762.5414672344923, y: -1456.9523466601968, z: 77.91 },
        { x: -756.644469935447, y: -1460.368300523609, z: 77.93 },
        { x: -754.4610880203545, y: -1461.6550271511078, z: 78.76 },
        { x: -746.576653342694, y: -1466.1585687585175, z: 81.47 },
      ];
      const points2 = [];
      rawPoints2.forEach((point) => {
        points2.push(new THREE.Vector3(point.x + 800, point.z, point.y + 800));
      });
      const randomSpline2 = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points2);
      const extrudeSettings2 = {
        steps: 30,
        bevelEnabled: false,
        extrudePath: randomSpline2,
      };
      const shape2Geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(
        wallShape,
        extrudeSettings2
      );
      const mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(shape2Geometry, material1);
      scene.add(mesh2);

      const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
      directionalLight.position.set(-1000, -1000, 10);
      // scene.add( directionalLight );

      const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
      scene.add(light);

      camera.position.set(-740.261181384325, 0, -1502.8930274173617, 85);
      controls.update();

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code reference
https://jsfiddle.net/vishalsdeshmukh/xduzrc3v/14/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25626171/1461008. Also see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/search?q=frenet&type=issues.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley. I was able to avoid twisting of shape on Z axis and make it work as expected by commenting code (runtime)
if ( tz <= min ) {
   normal.set( 0, 0, 1 );
  }
is it possible to control this from outside OR I have to extend class and avoid doing this for my specific use case ?

Comment: You will have to handle it yourself. Alternatively, use modeling software and import your model.

Comment: Hi @WestLangley wanted to confirm this
from code here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/core/Curve.js#L262 if I comment line 338 & 362 i.e where it applies rotation, that should be only change right to avoid twisting of shape? apart from that it wont have any other impact right?

Comment: Yes, no other impact. For related, see: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/905#issuecomment-4556510.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for help. Works as per my need.