# How to create oblique cylinders/cones in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm struggling to work out how to draw an oblique cyclinder in three.js. Essentially, I would like to produce a cylinder with a top radius of r1 and a bottom radius of r2 (ie not the same radii), with the top and bottom of the cylinder offset by a particular factor, let's say x.

I might not want to draw 360 degrees of the cylinder, maybe only a portion of it (say 90 degrees).

[image]

I'm drawn to the cylinder function already present as this ticks most of the boxes that I want, as in I can give a start and end angle, and differing top and bottom radii. The only issue is trying to achieve the offset between the top and bottom.

I'm reasonably new to three.js, so there may be some technique or way to achieve this, but I've tried searching and haven't come up with anything that helps.

Comment: It's possible, but you'll need to adapt the default CylinderGeometry a bit for your use. Let me see if I can whip up an example...

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/12537141/1461008:  `geometry.applyMatrix4( new THREE.Matrix4().makeShear( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0 ) );`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this with a customized version of `CylinderGeometry`.

The code here is mostly borrowed from [CylinderGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/8921bfaee413e809cb2d27f0aec917408d690a0f/src/geometries/CylinderGeometry.js), but with the change that instead of defining a start and end radius, you pass in a function that gets called for each "layer" of the cylinder, and it needs to return a 4-array of numbers: `[centerX, layerY, centerZ, radius]`.

This allows for cylinder- and cone-like geometries with an uneven height and center.

For instance, [in the example in the CodeSandbox where I sketched this out](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-cylinder-geometry-pwyxgu?file=/src/CustomCylinderGeometry.ts), the function is

```
const coordFunc = (i, t) => {
    const j = i / t; // 0 .. 1
    const x = Math.sin(j * 3) * 2;
    const y = Math.cos(j * 3) * 2;
    return [x, height / 2 - height * j, y, radius * (j * j) + 0.5];
};
```

and the result is a funky spiraling vase of sorts:

[image]

For a skewed cylinder, you'd want something simpler:

```
return [j * 5, height * j, 0, radius];
```

yields

[image]

---

```
import {
  BufferGeometry,
  Float32BufferAttribute,
  Vector3,
  Vector2
} from "three";

export default class CustomCylinderGeometry extends BufferGeometry {
  constructor(
    heightSegmentFunction, // (i, t) => [x, y, z, radius]
    radialSegments = 8,
    heightSegments = 1,
    openEnded = false,
    thetaStart = 0,
    thetaLength = Math.PI * 2
  ) {
    super();
    this.type = "AdvancedCylinderGeometry";

    const scope = this;

    radialSegments = Math.floor(radialSegments);
    heightSegments = Math.floor(heightSegments);
    const [, , , radiusBottom] = heightSegmentFunction(0, heightSegments);
    const [, height, , radiusTop] = heightSegmentFunction(
      heightSegments,
      heightSegments
    );

    // buffers

    const indices = [];
    const vertices = [];
    const normals = [];
    const uvs = [];

    // helper variables

    let index = 0;
    const indexArray = [];
    let groupStart = 0;

    // generate geometry

    generateTorso();

    if (openEnded === false) {
      if (radiusTop > 0) generateCap(true);
      if (radiusBottom > 0) generateCap(false);
    }

    // build geometry

    this.setIndex(indices);
    this.setAttribute("position", new Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    this.setAttribute("normal", new Float32BufferAttribute(normals, 3));
    this.setAttribute("uv", new Float32BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));

    function generateTorso() {
      const normal = new Vector3();
      const vertex = new Vector3();

      let groupCount = 0;

      // this will be used to calculate the normal
      const slope = (radiusBottom - radiusTop) / height;

      // generate vertices, normals and uvs

      for (let y = 0; y <= heightSegments; y++) {
        const [cx, cy, cz, radius] = heightSegmentFunction(y, heightSegments);
        const indexRow = [];

        const v = y / heightSegments;

        // calculate the radius of the current row

        //const radius = v * (radiusBottom - radiusTop) + radiusTop;

        for (let x = 0; x <= radialSegments; x++) {
          const u = x / radialSegments;
          const theta = u * thetaLength + thetaStart;
          const sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
          const cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
          vertex.x = cx + radius * sinTheta;
          vertex.y = cy;
          vertex.z = cz + radius * cosTheta;
          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
          normal.set(sinTheta, slope, cosTheta).normalize();
          normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z); // TODO: probably not correct
          uvs.push(u, 1 - v);
          indexRow.push(index++);
        }
        indexArray.push(indexRow);
      }

      // generate indices

      for (let x = 0; x < radialSegments; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < heightSegments; y++) {
          // we use the index array to access the correct indices

          const a = indexArray[y][x];
          const b = indexArray[y + 1][x];
          const c = indexArray[y + 1][x + 1];
          const d = indexArray[y][x + 1];

          // faces

          indices.push(a, b, d);
          indices.push(b, c, d);

          // update group counter

          groupCount += 6;
        }
      }

      // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

      scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

      // calculate new start value for groups

      groupStart += groupCount;
    }

    function generateCap(top) {
      // save the index of the first center vertex
      const centerIndexStart = index;

      const uv = new Vector2();
      const vertex = new Vector3();

      let groupCount = 0;

      const sign = top === true ? 1 : -1;
      const [cx, cy, cz, radius] = heightSegmentFunction(
        top ? 0 : heightSegments,
        heightSegments
      );

      // first we generate the center vertex data of the cap.
      // because the geometry needs one set of uvs per face,
      // we must generate a center vertex per face/segment

      for (let x = 1; x <= radialSegments; x++) {
        vertices.push(cx, cy, cz);
        normals.push(0, sign, 0);
        uvs.push(0.5, 0.5);
        index++;
      }

      // save the index of the last center vertex
      const centerIndexEnd = index;

      // now we generate the surrounding vertices, normals and uvs

      for (let x = 0; x <= radialSegments; x++) {
        const u = x / radialSegments;
        const theta = u * thetaLength + thetaStart;

        const cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
        const sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
        vertex.x = cx + radius * sinTheta;
        vertex.y = cy;
        vertex.z = cz + radius * cosTheta;
        vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
        normals.push(0, sign, 0);
        uv.x = cosTheta * 0.5 + 0.5;
        uv.y = sinTheta * 0.5 * sign + 0.5;
        uvs.push(uv.x, uv.y);
        index++;
      }

      // generate indices

      for (let x = 0; x < radialSegments; x++) {
        const c = centerIndexStart + x;
        const i = centerIndexEnd + x;

        if (top === true) {
          indices.push(i, i + 1, c);
        } else {
          indices.push(i + 1, i, c);
        }

        groupCount += 3;
      }
      scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, top === true ? 1 : 2);
      groupStart += groupCount;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution as being new to three.js, the comment in the example help a lot. Just wondering though, I can't see how to introduce a different radius at the top and bottom?

Comment: The 4th number returned by the function is there radius at that height. `5*j` gets you a cone with base radius 5.

Comment: @Pi31 With the same success you can deform `THREE.CylinderGeometry`, setting its height, also top and bottom radii, accessing vertices via `geometry.attributes.position`.